# About parametric resonance

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the same equation with little difference: 
$\ddot{x} +w^2(t) x=0$.
Where $w^2=w_0^2 [1+h\cos\gamma t]^2$, where $h\ll 1$ and $\gamma =2 w_0 + \varepsilon$.
How can I prove analytically parametric resonance condition i.e. $\gamma =2w/n $ and and can I get  the solution using perturbation series expansion in h. I started with $ x= \sum x_i(t) \cdot h^i$.
But with this I am unable to get $\varepsilon$ contribution in my solution for order $1$ in $h$.